# How do I toggle (add/remove) shapefile layers in Leaflet.js?

Tags: shapefile, leaflet

If I create a shapefile layer

```
var ac_shpfile = new L.Shapefile("data/AC.zip", {onEachFeature: function (feature, layer) {
/* Add some colors based on shapefile features */
}});
```

and then add it to the map I've created

```
ac_shpfile.addTo(map);
```

How do I later remove that shapefile layer from the map? I plan to create another shapefile layer (same shapefile but with different colorings) and based on some user action switch between these two shapefile layers being shown. How do I add/remove shapefile layers like this? I've looked for the "opposite" of `addTo()` in the documentation but this doesn't seem tot be easy to find?

Comment: typically it would be map.removeLayer(shapefile) but it depends on whether the shapefile plugin supports that api

Comment: Ok, thanks! It does seem that the shapefile plugin supports this, and I am getting the effect that I wanted. If you post your response as an answer I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like [the Leaflet Shapefile plugin](https://github.com/calvinmetcalf/leaflet.shapefile) has implemented `L.Shapefile` as an extension of [L.GeoJson](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#geojson). `L.GeoJson` implements the `ILayer` interface, including the method [removeLayer()](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#map-removelayer)

Long way of saying that this should work:

```
map.removeLayer(shapefile)
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out [this](http://leafletjs.com/examples/layers-control.html) example.

Based on your code snippet, you can do something like this:

```
var ac_shpfile = new L.Shapefile("data/AC.zip", {onEachFeature: function (feature, layer) {
    /* Add some colors based on shapefile features */
    }});

var baseMaps = {
    //"example title": example_layer
};

var overlayMaps = {
    "AC Shapefile": ac_shpfile
};

L.control.layers(baseMaps, overlayMaps).addTo(map);
```

That will give you a toggleable layer control.

Otherwise do it in code, as noted above:

```
ac_shpfile.addTo(map);
map.removeLayer(ac_shpfile)
```